# How to get all visible UI elements in iOS at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get all visible elements on screen at runtime in Swift 5.0 on the iOS Platform?

Comment: What OS? Please [edit] your question and provide more details about what you have tried and what problem you are having.

Comment: iOS is the platform I am referencing.

Comment: You could iterate through all the subviews of each `UIView` starting from the main window, but you'll get a lot of things you probably won't need. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to know what are all of the possible UI elements so I can test which ones are on screen at the moment and interact with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that basically.

Add this code on your ViewController. I recommend create a new swift file call it UIViewExtension.

```
    extension UIView
   {
      public var allSubviews: [UIView]
      {
          return self.subviews.flatMap { [$0] + $0.allSubviews }
       }
    }
```

Now call this method when you need all visible elements.

```
   public func allVisibleElements()
   {
     for subview in self.view.allSubviews
     {
        if (!subview.isHidden)
        {
           //ok you are done!. 
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I'd add to that `allAccessibleElements()` where each item that is a subView and is not hidden that has an accessibility tag and has accessibility enabled.  This would be GREAT to check for items when UI Testing before calling them.